# Count the whole possible dataset in typeorm

Tags: typeorm

My backend is in `node.js`, the DB is `MongoDB` and I am using `typeorm` for handling entities.

I have a "get data for this table" like endpoint (the unimportant parts skipped):

```
  public static async tableList<T>(params: ...): Promise<...<T>>{
    try {
      const repository = await getRepository(this.name);
      
      const whereConditions = [{ ... }];  // created from params
  
      let orderCondition = [{ ...  }]; // created from params

      let conditions = {take: params.take, skip: params.skip, where: wherewhereConditions order: orderCondition};

      return await repository.find(conditions);
    } catch (error) {
 ...
   }
  }
```

This works just fine. You can tell set the take and skip params, and it will only send the currently displayed data in the table:

[image: Screenshot of the table paginator]

So for example, in this case, it sends only 25 items, from the 25th to the 50th.

Now, I need to display the possible max count of the data in the db for pagination purposes. Is there a way, to make **typeorm** count the possible data?

My solution feels bad: I have nearly a million entries in a specific collection, and would like to avoid loading them in the memory, with `.find()` without `take` and `skip`, just to get a `.length` value from it. But I still need to apply the filter logic somehow...

**Update**
I have tried this:

```
      const entities = await repository.find(conditions);
      const count2 = await repository.count(conditions);
```

But the `count` call returns "unkonw operator:$and" error, which is quite strange as the two function from `Repository.d.ts` shows the same parameter list. I guess MongoDB doesn't have an implementation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `count()` is faulty, or I misuse it somehow.

But the following code works:

```
let [entities, count] = await repository.findAndCount();
```

And it returns just what I need for the `count` variable.